# Fetch multi level node from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the "friends" from the node to be able to show them in `UICollectionView` afterwards. I now realized that I have to use a struct and place the Friends array inside. I am struggling now to understand how to fetch them into that array (you can see it at the bottom of the post). Data is stored in a firebase node. How can I grab the data and what would be the procedure to place it in `UICollectionView` afterwards? This is my function so far to retrieve.

UPDATE: (I think I am fetching correctly now but I don't get any results. Is there something that I should do in collection view? or what am I doing wrong?)

UPDATE: Here is my code for post fetching:

```
func fetchPosts3() {

    ref.child("Users_Posts").child("\(unique)").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)

        if snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] != nil {

            let allPosts = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            self.posts.removeAll()

            for (_, value) in allPosts {

                if  let postID = value["postID"] as? String,
                    let userIDDD = value["userID"] as? String

                {
                    //ACCESS FRIENDS
                    ref.child("Users_Posts").child("\(unique)").child(postID).child("friends").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        print("FRIENDS: \(snap.childrenCount)")

                        //var routine = self.postsWithFriends[0].friends
                        for friendSnap in snap.children {
                            if let friendSnapshot = friendSnap as? DataSnapshot  {

                                let friendDict = friendSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                                let friendName = friendDict?["name"] as? String
                                let friendPostID = friendDict?["postID"] as? String

                                let postsToShow = PostWithFriends(id: userIDDD, friends: [Friend(friendName: friendName!, friendPostID: friendPostID!)])

                                self.postsWithFriends.append(postsToShow)
                                print("COUNTING: \(self.postsWithFriends.count)")

                                // then do whatever you need with your friendOnPost
                            }
                        }


                    })
                }
            }
            //GET LOCATION

            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            self.posts.sort(by: {$0.intervalPosts! > $1.intervalPosts!})


        }
    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

That's how the data looks at the database:

```
{
    "-LN2rl2414KAISO_qcK_" : {
        "cellID" : "2",
        "city" : "Reading",
        "date" : "2018-09-23 00:41:26 +0000",
        "friends" : {
            "UJDB35HDTIdssCtZfEsMbDDmBYw2" : {
                "name" : "Natalia",
                "postID" : "-LN2rl2414KAISO_qcK_",
                "userID" : "UJDB35HDTIdssCtZfEsMbDDmBYw2"
            },
            "Vyobk7hJu5OGzOe7E1fcYTbMvVI2" : {
                "name" : "Gina C",
                "postID" : "-LN2rl2414KAISO_qcK_",
                "userID" : "Vyobk7hJu5OGzOe7E1fcYTbMvVI2"
            }
        },
    }
}
```

And this is my object that's stored into array

```
struct PostWithFriends {
    var postID : String?
    var friends: [Friend]
}

class Friend : NSObject {
    var friendName: String?
    var friendUserID: String?
    var postID: String?

    init(friendName: String, friendPostID: String) {
        self.friendName = friendName
        self.postID = friendPostID
    }
}
```

Comment: To achieve what? What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry Yury, I was not clear with the question, I've made some changes now.

Comment: The initial question was to retrieve the data from firebase, so my answer was about that, since you changed the question, you need to show us the code about your collection view implementation

Comment: I am sorry DionizB, your answer was what I was looking for. I thought I already marked the answer. I got to distracted!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
if let friend = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

}
```

With this:

```
for friendSnap in snap.children {
    if let friendSnapshot = friendSnap as? FIRDataSnapshot  {
        let friendOnPost = FriendOnPost()
        let friendDict = friendSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        friendOnPost.name = friendDict?["name"] as? String
        friendOnPost.friendUserID = friendDict?["userID"] as? String
        friendOnPost.postID = friendDict?["postID"] as? String
        // then do whatever you need with your friendOnPost
    }
}
```